# reading configuration from text file

Tags: r, rjava

I have a txt file which has entries

```
indexUrl=http://192.168.2.105:9200
jarFilePath = /home/soumy/lib
```

How can I read this file from R and get the value of `jarFilePath` ?

I need this to set the `.jaddClassPath()`... I have problem to copying the jar to classpath because of the difference in slashes in windows and linux

in linux I want to use

```
.jaddClassPath(dir("target/mavenLib", full.names=TRUE ))
```

but in windows

```
.jaddClassPath(dir("target\\mavenLib", full.names=TRUE ))
```

So thinking to read location of jar from property file !!!
If there is anyother alternative please let me know that also

Comment: For platform-specific file paths, you could check out `?file.path`.

Comment: I'd try using `readlines()` either to read the entire text file or in a loop, reading one line at a time.  Then find the elements (i.e. lines of text) containing "jarFilePath" using `which` or `grep` , and then `mypath <- gsub('jarFileaPath = ','',the_text_line)` .

Answer (score 6):

As of Sept 2016, CRAN has the package [properties](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/properties/).

It handles `=` in property values correctly (but does not handle spaces after the first `=` sign).

Example:

Contents of properties file `/tmp/my.properties`:

```
host=123.22.22.1
port=798
user=someone
pass=a=b
```

R code:

```
install.packages("properties")
library(properties)

myProps <- read.properties("/tmp/my.properties")
```

Then you can access the properties like `myProps$host`, etc., In particular, `myProps$pass` is `a=b` as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know whether a package offers a specific interface.

If not, I would first load the data in a data frame using read.table:

```
myProp <- read.table("path/to/file/filename.txt, header=FALSE, sep="=", row.names=1, strip.white=TRUE, na.strings="NA", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

`sep="="` is obviously the separator, this will nicely separate your property names and values.

`row.names=1` says the first column contains your row names, so you can index your data properties this way to retrieve each property you want.
For instance: `myProp["jarFilePath", 2]` will return `"/home/soumy/lib"`.

`strip.white=TRUE` will strip leading and trailing spaces you probably don't care about.

One could conveniently convert the loaded data frame into a named vector for a cleaner way to retrieve the property values: `myPropVec <- setNames(myProp[[2]], myProp[[1]])`.

Then to retrieve a property value from its name: `myPropVec["jarFilePath"]` will return `"/home/soumy/lib"` as well.

Comment: And by the way, a cleaner structure to access the properties would be to convert the data frame into a named vector.  Something like: `myProp <- setNames(myProp[[2]], myProp[[1]])`.  Thus accessing a property becomes: `myProp["jarFilePath"]`.

Comment: The call to setNames in the previous comment should be `myProp <- setNames(myProp[,1],row.names(myProp))`.

Comment: In the post, `myProp[[2]]` won't exist as it's written, so I believe `myProp[[2]]["jarFilePath"]` should be, e.g., `myProp["jarFilePath",1]`.

Comment: @Rahul Yes Rahul, good catch, as a data frame, the way to access the property was not correct, I am going to change it: it should be myProp["jarFilePath", 2] -- note the "2", not "1" as "1" is the property name, "2" the property value.  However, if converting the read data frame to a vector, I believe the setNames is correct as I posted it and offers a cleaner way to retrieve property values.  myPropVec <- setNames(myProp[, 2], row.names(myProp)) would be a rigorously equivalent alternative way to convert the data frame into a named vector.

Comment: I tried this out and I think the version I gave in the comments are correct. The reason is that because you have `row.names=1` in your call to `read.table` the returned  `data.frame` only has one column.

Comment: @RahulSavani OK, sorry if I misled anyone: if you tried then you must be right.  I did run some tests as well on the data structure but not as far as loading from file; I did not expect row.names=1 to drop the column, the doc does not mention such a behavior.